# Non-Alpha Sort of ASP.NET DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datagrid

I need to perform a customized sort of a .NET DataGrid. The `UserRole` column returns a set of three string values from SQL via a stored procedure: No Access, View, and Update.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="UserList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnDataBinding="UserList_DataBinding">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName ASC, LastName"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email Address"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UserRole" HeaderText="User Role" SortExpression="UserRole DESC, UserRole"></asp:BoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I need to be able to sort to display the "Update" value in the `UserRole` column at the top of the table. As it current sorts in descending order via the `SortExpression` property, "View" comes before "Update".

Where the above code is legacy code I'm not in a position to be able to full rewrite the code but is there another way to achieve this kind of custom non-alpha sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You should sort your data before binding it to the grid. Depending on how you access the underlying data you could use some sort of OrderBy clause and order DESC. If you simply want "Update" to be first, that will be a little harder.